# Fortify scan - ASP.NET Bad Practices: Non-Serializable Object Stored in Session

Tags: c#, security, fortify

Fortify scan - ASP.NET Bad Practices: Non-Serializable Object Stored in Session

Fortify scan gave "ASP.NET Bad Practices: Non-Serializable Object Stored in Session" for some code like this:

```
Session["EnteredSearchParameter"] = new List<EnteredSearchParameter>();
```

The class EnteredSearchParameter just have one public string property.

Tried Fortify's recommendations:

1. Mark EnteredSearchParameter as [Serializable]
2. Make EnteredSearchParameter to implement ISerializable

Did not resolve the issue

Any suggestions?

Comment: `List` is serializable, so marking `EnteredSearchParameter` with `SerializableAttribute` should has resolved this issue.

Comment: I know it should have, very frustrating
Thanks!